# AWS Elastic BeanStalk SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I created an Elastic Beanstalk Environment using windows Power shell and i followed this deployment document [Deploying a Django Application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)

I done these steps:
Python Virtual Environment with Django,

created django project,

create IAM user i got Access Key ID and Secret Access Key ID

failing this step environment and deploy your Django application

when ever i try `eb init` it asking access key, secret access key and region aws application auto generated names after done these steps i am getting this error

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details
```

I am new to deployment please help me any one

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: This error means that the AWS signing process is incorrect which is usually a software bug. Are you behind a proxy or something that could interfere? What version of the AWS CLI and EB CLI do you have installed?

Comment: @John Hanley  AWS CLI  version  aws-cli/1.16.26 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.16

Comment: It means any antivirus causing problem or any software issue

Comment: You forgot the EB CLI version. I have 3.14.6 installed and I use it every day.

Comment: Sorry  EB CLI Version AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.6.5

Comment: First item to complete: update your EB CLI.

Comment: @John Hanley Sure ... i will do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181262/discussion-between-somesh-and-john-hanley).

Comment: I just posted the answer for your problem. I am stopping for the evening now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using EB CLI version 2.x. This is deprecated and no longer supported. The base set of commands changed with version 3.x.

[The Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)

The solution is to install the latest version.

[Install the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html)

Comment: I updated my EB CLI version but still same error issue is while installing EB CLI version shows awsebcli-3.14.6 and if i try this command  eb --version it show AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface v2.6.5 what should i do

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: awsebcli in c:\users\mehul\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (3.14.6)

Comment: I uninstalled EB CLI and installed again now its working @ John HanleyThank   you so much ...